# Linux find and copy files with same name to destination folder do not overwrite

Tags: linux, find, cp

I want to find and copy all files with `*.jpg` in one folder includes its sub folder to another folder
I use

```
find /tempL/6453/ -name "*.jpg" |  xargs  -I  '{}' cp {} /tempL/;
```

but it overwrite files with same name

for example in `/tempL/6453/`, there are `test (1).jpg` `test (2).jpg` and folder 1, in `/tempL/6453/1/`, there are also have files with the same name `test (1).jpg`  `test (2).jpg`

If I use the above command, there are only two files `test (1).jpg` `test (2).jpg` in `/tempL/`, it can not copy all files to `/tempL/`.

What I want is to copy all files to `/tempL/`, when there are same file name, just rename them, how to?

Comment: cp *.jpg PUT_DESTINATION_PATH

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Please read the question carefully. Admittedly it could be worded better but it's clear that the OP wants to rename files that have the same name in any of the source directories. Your suggestions do not rename and do not recurse the source subdirectories.

Comment: @kaylum, sorry didnt understand it 100%, and also not sure about recurse but wouldn't it use -r?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI `-r` is indeed for recursing directories. But it has no effect unless the source is a directory. `*.jpg` is not a directory. And if you don't understand the question then best to ask for clarification first.

Comment: @kaylum ah gotcha, thank you for the clarification. Sorry I wasn't able to answer this question, but I am looking forward to seeing what the answer is!

Answer (score 7):

> What I want is to copy all files to /tempL/, when there are same file name, just rename them, how to?

1) If you only do not what overwrite `cp --backup` will give you a backup for existing file, with `--suffix` option of `cp`, you can also specify the suffix to be used for backup.

2) `--parents` option of `cp`will keep directory tree, i.e. files in folder 1 will be copy to new created 1 folder.

3) If you want to customize your rename processing, you can not use `cp` command only. write script for it and call it to process the result of `find`

Answer (score 2):

Install "GNU parallel" and use:

```
find /tempL/6453/ -name "*.jpg" | parallel 'cp {} ./dest-dir/`stat -c%i {}`_{/}'

{/}  ................. gets filename with no full path
```

I think the same approach should be possible with xargs, but learning about parallel was amazing for me, it gives us many beautiful solutions.

I recommend using `echo` before `cp` in order to test your command

Comment: Try also `--dry-run` instead of `echo`. It will also work for commands like 'seq 10 | parallel 'ls {} || echo Not found {}'`

Answer (score 0):

Below is a tested and working implementation.

---

**MODEL**

```
#!/bin/bash

find "<SOME_FOLDER_PATH>" -type f "<SOME_FIND_ARG>" -exec sh -c '
    DESTINATION_DIR="<SOME_DESTINY_FOLDER>"
    for FOUND_FILE do
        BASE_NAME=$(basename "$FOUND_FILE")
        if [ -f "$DESTINATION_DIR/$BASE_NAME" ]; then
            cp "$FOUND_FILE" "$DESTINATION_DIR/$BASE_NAME-$(uuidgen | cut -d "-" -f 2)"
        else
            cp "$FOUND_FILE" "$DESTINATION_DIR/$BASE_NAME"
        fi
    done
' bash {} +
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
#!/bin/bash

find "/some/folder/path/" -type f -iname "*some_find_arg*" -exec sh -c '
    DESTINATION_DIR="/some/destiny/folder"
    for FOUND_FILE do
        BASE_NAME=$(basename "$FOUND_FILE")
        if [ -f "$DESTINATION_DIR/$BASE_NAME" ]; then
            cp "$FOUND_FILE" "$DESTINATION_DIR/$BASE_NAME-$(uuidgen | cut -d "-" -f 2)"
        else
            cp "$FOUND_FILE" "$DESTINATION_DIR/$BASE_NAME"
        fi
    done
' bash {} +
```

---

**EXTRA:** Remove duplicate files...

**EXAMPLE**

```
cd "/some/destiny/folder"
fdupes -rdN ./

# r - recursive
# d - preserve first file, delete other dupes
# N - run silently (no prompt)
```